# Славянские имена. Тамила

Tags: ономастика

Тамила -- это древнеславянское имя?

Comment: Шампар, если не хотите получить ярлык кацапа, не используйте беспричинно подобный презрительные клички.

Answer (score 2):

В Интернете много информации об этом имени,  в основном они считается славянским, например:

"Тамила – томная (старославянское)".

"Женское имя Тамила имеет славянское происхождение. Древнерусский глагол «томити», имевший значения «томить», «терзать», «мучить», стал для него первоосновой. Значение имени – «томная», «мучительница». Имя популярно в Украине, в России оно встречается в несколько других вариациях – Тамела, Томилла, Тамелла".

"У моей мамы имя Тамилла (паспортистка, почему-то, написала с двумя "л"), она родом из Беларуси. Её даже крестили там в православном храме этим именем. В семье её ласково называли Милочкой. Интересное имя".

Comment: Sibylla, это не может быть древнеславянским именем. Просто нет документальной фиксации, ни его, ни аналогов. Вообще все т. н. славянские имена выдуманы жуковским со товарищи не ранее середины XVIII века. А уж выводить этимологию из на сосновании данных столь сомнительных источников  - это ниже всякой критики. Томило - это то чем томят, а не кто томит (как мыло, рыло или шило. У суффикса -ло (-ла) не может семантики тот, кто, оно просто не нужно. для этого были и есть -арь, -ец, и т. п.  (бондарь, купец, и проч). Про немотивированный переход корневого "о" в "а", я даже не говорю.

Comment: При всем уважении к Вашей маме.

Comment: Да, мне это имя тоже не кажется славянским, но тем интереснее было бы узнать его истинное происхождение, чтобы опровергнуть общепринятую версию вместе с   ее сомнительными источниками.

Answer (score 0):

Вот ни разу не сталкивался. А почему такая идея, где фиксируется, к какому слову восходит?

Кстати, если имя женское, то точно нет. Женщин у славян за пределами семьи называли в основном по отчествам.
(+)====

Поскольку появилась версия совершенно на мой взгляд фантастическая (или вернее сказать, фантазийная), пробежался по источникам. 
Вот немного набор более или менее правдободобных сведений.

1. Прежде всего, имя Томило - мужское, как я и думал. Переделка на женское возможно, но это никак не может быть результатом переосмысления, более древнего, чем вековой давности.
2. Имя не древнеславянское, а русское и недавнее, Успенский и некоторые другие источники свидетельствуют, что популярно было в XVI-XVII веках.
3. Образовано, тоже как я и предполагал, по образцу "шило" или "било".  Близкий аналог - имя Шумило. В обоих случаях значение именно пассивного воздействия, инструментального, но не прямого субъекта дейстивия, т. е. в современных понятиях - скорее то, "чем шумят, томят", чем "кто шумит, томит".
4. Единственный нефантастический (но тоже не достоверный) вариант этимологии - ребенок, "утомивший", измучивший мать при своем рождении, рожденный в муках. Эти и объясняется распространенность имени. Такое отвлеченное качество как "томность" никак не могло стать основой имени. Не характерно совершенно.

Итак. Если возводить к "томности", то придется признать современное переосмысление, включая орфографию, хронологию и этимологию. Древнеславянского в "Тамиле" нет ничего.

Comment: мужское, конечно. От женских имен фамилии Томилин, Шумилин не могли бы образоваться.

Answer (score 0):

Краткий перечень известных женщин с именем Тамила говорит, что в России имя это не так популярно, как пишут: Сагаипова (род. 1993) российская певица, Тамила (Тамилла) Полежаева (ум.2011) топ-лидер компании «Oriflame», Тамила Ширалиева (балетмейстер, АзССР), Тамила Евдокимова (советский тренер по гимнастике, УССР), Тамила Агамирова род. 1928 (советская актриса, театр «Ромэн»), Тамила Мухамедова (советская киноактриса), Тамила Джоджуа (российская журналистка), Тамила Покуса («Учитель года» 2009), Тамила Цагареишвили (грузинский этнолог), Тамила Олексюк (советская гандболистка).

В сети не встречается (при толковании — томная и т.п.) внятного объяснения замены ударной О на А, а также обилия вариаций имени, при том что множественность не в характере славянских имён (о других помолчим). Вариации имени с удвоенными согласными тоже никак не подтверждают стародавнее и славянское происхождение этого имени.